# how to retrieve the present url in a browser and embed in php file

Tags: php, url, pdf, browser

Hello i am working with a free api for converting webpages to pdf, it works perfectly by inputing a url into the snippet, but what i want to achieve is to convert my dynamiclly generated pages to pdf, but am nt gettin the correct way to do this, i have tried posting the dynamic url to the php file but it dosent work, so am asking if theres a method to get the present url of a browser, and append to where the url is to be placed

this is what i have tried

```
<?php
        $pdf = file_get_contents('http://api.simplehtmltopdf.com/?link=$_POST[link]&orientation=Portrait&mtop=10&mright=10&mleft=10&mbot=0');
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Accept-Ranges: none");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"your_pdf_name.pdf\"");
        echo $pdf;
?>
```

this is the initial snippet that works

```
 <?php
        $pdf = file_get_contents('http://api.simplehtmltopdf.com/?link=http://google.com&orientation=Portrait&mtop=10&mright=10&mleft=10&mbot=0');
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Accept-Ranges: none");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"your_pdf_name.pdf\"");
        echo $pdf;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current url of the page using php by

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
 $current_page_url = curPageURL();
```

Then using **curl**

For example

```
$Curl_Session = curl_init('url of your php file which one convert web page to pdf');
                    curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "current_url=**$current_page_url** ");
                    curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    $res = curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
                    curl_close ($Curl_Session);
```

Then make the following change in your pdf_converter file

```
<?php
        $current_url = $_POST['current_url'];
        $pdf = file_get_contents('http://api.simplehtmltopdf.com/?link=**$current_url**');
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Accept-Ranges: none");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"your_pdf_name.pdf\"");
        echo $pdf;
?>
```

Comment: so how do i apply it the snippet i gave pls

Comment: Which file show the dynamic content with dynamic url??

Comment: cssss.php?Transaction_id=ksksdgsdgshdgsdfshvc026265275373232327224sbxsdyusxseMceIUHaqcDxsiKmREaDbFSwu

Comment: ok let try this.. in this cssss.php file copy the first snippet and try to echo the  $current_page_url value..

Comment: If it works then copy the second snippet. Here the main changes is set your pdf_converter file path

Comment: $current_page_url gives a blank page

Comment: or maybe i didnt get u properly

Comment: alll i get is blank pages, am testing using localhost though

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$page = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];


<?php
$pdf = file_get_contents('http://api.simplehtmltopdf.com/?link='.$page.'&orientation=Portrait&mtop=10&mright=10&mleft=10&mbot=0'); 
header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Accept-Ranges: none"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"your_pdf_name.pdf\"");
echo $pdf;
```

OR for URL with query string

```
<?php
    $pdf = file_get_contents('http://api.simplehtmltopdf.com/?link='.$page.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&orientation=Portrait&mtop=10&mright=10&mleft=10&mbot=0'); 
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"your_pdf_name.pdf\"");
    echo $pdf;
```

Comment: aiite let me try this out